# How facebook call-to-action button runs ios application

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking, facebook-call-to-action

I'm trying to create call-to-action button that will open my app.
What I've done:

1 . Added url scheme to my up.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myapp</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myid.myapp</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

2 . Added metadata to my website.

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://open"/>
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345"/>
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="My App"/>
```

3 . Added a link with the deeplink on my site. It works great and launches my app.

```
<a href="myapp://open">Run the app</a>
```

4 . Added call-to-action button on my facebook page, filled al the fields with:

- web-site: url to my website;
- ios deeplink: myapp://open;
- app store url: app store url;

But clicking on the call-to-action button always leads to appstore.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks don't answer some questons:

1. How does facebook know that metadata locates on my website? I mean, when facebook searches for metadata, how does it know that it must search on my website?
2. If Facebook just opens deeplink, why doesnot it open my app?

Comment: _“I mean, when facebook searches for metadata, how does it know that it must search on my website?”_ – because you did put the URL into the website field of the CTA button options …?

Comment: then if it looks there, why it doesnot open my app? All the metadata is right there on the site I specified in the website field

Comment: Have you checked your meta tags via debug tool already? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: url, app_store_id and app_name are ok, some warnings about "og" data and the "Share App ID Missing" warning

Comment: I've actually never had much luck understanding how Facebook implements their own standards. It seems to change all the time. But if you want a more reliable alternative to accomplish the same thing, take a look at [Branch.io](https://branch.io). We do conform to all the App Links standards, but we also do backup redirects to make sure if App Links fail, the user still ends up in the app anyway.